# How do I access the value attribute within a div using php?

Tags: php, html, css

For example I have this line of html within form tags.

```
<form action="getData.php" method="post">
    <div id="imadiv" value="2"></div>
</form>
```

How would I retrieve the value of the 'value' attribute so that I can use fwrite() to put it on a document using PHP?

Comment: why does the `div` have a `value` attribute?

Comment: change the `<div>` to a hidden input, `<input type="hidden" name="imadiv" value="2">` ??

Comment: The short answer is: you can't with PHP alone. It is not sent to the server upon form submission. Use JavaScript to get the value of this attribute and send it to your PHP script using AJAX (using a framework like jQuery can make this a lot easier). (Also, **`<div>` tag does not have a `value` property**)

Comment: who cares about the `value` semantics? No reader will complain. If one eagers to pass a validator test, use `data-value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you parsing html files that have this structure and need to access the value in order to create another document?

If not, then your form handler will have access to the value of "imadiv" (in this example) when you make your post.

if you were do do something like this

```
<form action="getData.php" method="post">
  <input name="inputname" value="2"/>
</form>
```

and submit that form getData.php could do something like

```
$valueofinput = $_POST['inputname']
```

Giving your input tags a name attribute it important to reading the values out of the post payload.

If you're parsing HTML files with forms then I would suggest looking at XML/HTML parsing libraries that will help you access the html as a object node structure.

If you are doing something a little more complex where you want to validate the the data as the use enters, then you'll need to implement an ajax solution. However, keep in mind that connecting the post to key events can get messy as you could end up sending more requests than you originally wanted to if not implemented correctly.